# ErrorException [ Warning ]: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, kohana-3

I am trying to sort the array value in ascending order and again i need to print that values in user screen.

views.php

```
$event_array =  (array)$events;
$sorted_value = asort($event_array);

foreach($sorted_value as $event):
if($event->event_date >= $cdate):
```

Update:

```
$event_array =  (array)$events;
$sorted_value = asort($event_array);

foreach($events as $key => $val):
    echo "$key = $val->event_from_time\n";
if($val->event_date >= $cdate):
$color = '#FFFFFF';
    $textcolor = '#38CBF0';
   else:
    $color = '#FFFFFF';
   $textcolor = '#38CBF0';
   endif;  
$userid_count = $val->event_members_count;
```

I am getting the error in `foreach` loop it is "`ErrorException [ Warning ]: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`"

1st thing is the sorting code what i used is correct or incorrect.

I need to iterate the sorted array and display the result to user.How to solve this exception.

Thanks

Comment: print_r($sorted_value) abd see whats there.

Comment: What did you assign to `$event`?

Comment: asort() returns boolean.

Comment: Please RTFM for how to use `asort`.

Comment: How to sort the array value in ascending order.

Comment: @Yeah How to sort the array value in ascending order

Comment: @user2681579 asort sorts the array value in ascending or low to high order. Read this page for more [info](http://in3.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: @Yeah referred that and tried to arrange the values in array and i want to print that sorted values in page.Now i solved that issue but the value is not getting sorted.Please help me in solving this.Please see my update

Comment: @Fabio $events hold the object,also i updated my question.Please help me in sorting the values in ascending order

Comment: *sigh* Since you apparently have not RTFM yet: To sort an array you do `asort($array);`. Nothing more, nothing less. No `$array = asort($array);`. Only `asort($array);`.